# Django M2M Through extra fields with multiple models

Tags: python, django, relationship, m2m

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up the following django model (genericised for security reasons).

```
ThingA:
    User(M2M through "UserRelation")

ThingB:
    User(M2M through "UserRelation")

ThingC:
    User(M2M through "UserRelation")

User:
    Login_name

UserRelation:
    User (foreginkey)
    Thing (foreignkey) #is this generic to any of the above "things"
    Privilege
```

I understand using "through" between two distinct models, but I'm not sure how to apply this to multiple models. Would I define a foreignkey for each of the "Thing" models in my UserRelation Model?

Comment: How do the thing models differ ? are they entirely different, or does it have common properties, etc?

Comment: they are entirely different. So thingA might be like School, and thingB might be like Houses

Comment: I think I see where you're getting at. Could I do something like a base model for each thing that has the user m2m field. then the relationship field could reference the base model instead?

Comment: Having a separate column for each type would make it a sparse table. I would just have separate relationship tables. Another thing I would look into is see if `GenericForiegnKey` relations would be appropriate in this context (again not entirely convinced because you cannot leverage the power of M2M in this case).

Comment: That was my initial thought, but having the base referenced model would add unnecessary lookups to identify the type, etc..

Comment: In this case I think that is ok, as reverse lookup isn't important to the application (i.e. I dont need to work backwards from the user to the object)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to setup a generic many-to-many relationship. There is a dedicated django app that you can be use for this purpose: [django-gm2m](http://django-gm2m.readthedocs.org/en/release)

Here is how to use it in your generic case:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey

from gm2m import GM2MField


class ThingA(models.Model):
    pass

class ThingB(models.Model):
    pass

class ThingC(models.Model):
    pass

class User(models.Model):
     login_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     things = GM2MField(through='UserRelation')

class UserRelation(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     thing = GenericForeignKey(ct_field='thing_ct', fk_field='thing_fk')
     thing_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
     thing_fk = models.CharField(max_length=255)

     privilege = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

You can now access all the `things` for a given user and all the `User` instances for a given 'thing', as well as the privilege attribute for each `UserRelation` instance.

This will additionally provide you with a handful of benefits (reverse relations, prefetching, etc.) you may need. A `GM2MField` basically behaves exactly like a django `ManyToManyField`.

Disclaimer: I am the author of [django-gm2m](http://django-gm2m.readthedocs.org/en/release)

Comment: So how then do you access it in reverse when you have a "through" relation?

Comment: I made that comment of mine into a question instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768568/reverse-relations-with-django-gm2m-using-through-relation