# Reverse relations with django-gm2m using "through" relation

Tags: python, django, m2m

I don't understand how to follow many-to-many relations in the reverse direction with django-gm2m. Here is an example of an models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from gm2m import GM2MField

class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    pass

class X(models.Model):
    things = GM2MField()

class Y(models.Model):
    things = GM2MField(through='Yrel')

class Yrel(models.Model):
    y = models.ForeignKey(Y)
    thing = GenericForeignKey(ct_field='thing_ct', fk_field='thing_fk')
    thing_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    thing_fk = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

X and Y both have "things" which contains several arbitrary objects. It is Y I have problems with, and X is only for comparison.

I have a few objects to test with.

```
a1, a2, b1 = A(), A(), B()
a1.save()
a2.save()
b1.save()
```

etc. With the class X I can do

```
x1, x2 = X(), X()
x1.save()
x2.save()
x1.things.add(a1, b1)
x2.things.add(a1)
```

and then get the added things back with `x1.things.all()` etc. To go in the reverse direction I use `x_set` as in `a1.x_set.count()`.

So far so good. With "Y" that uses "through" I do

```
y1 = Y()
y1.save()
Yrel(y=y1, thing=a1).save()
Yrel(y=y1, thing=a2).save()
```

to add two "things", and then I can get the list back with `y1.things.all()` again. But how can I do a reverse lookup from `a1` to see where it is used?

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) help?

Answer (score 0):

As described [in the documentation](https://django-gm2m.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features.html#automatic-creation) django-gm2m can only create the related reverse relation after you have added an instance to the `*_set` (as you did with the `X` objects), as it can't know on which models the reverse relation is needed.

If you would like to access the reverse relations without having added something before you need to [specify on which models they should get created](https://django-gm2m.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features.html#manual-creation):

```
class Y(models.Model):
    things = GM2MField(through='Yrel', A, B)
```

This somehow resembles Django's behaviour where you would also have to create the reverse relation for `GenericForeignKey` [manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations).

Comment: "... after you have added an instance to the *_set": So how do I do that? I can't do `y1.things.add(a1)`. That yields an AttributeError and tells me to use Yrel's manager instead. The commands in my questions are how I think it should be done instead.

Comment: It's totally fine as you do it if you want to use the through model like that, but then just let the `GM2MField` know on which models (`A`, `B`) it should create the reverse relations, like in the example I posted...

Comment: Thanks, but both from the documentation and from what you write it seems like there is another way, where I don't have to explicitly create those relations, but they are created the first time an object gets such a relation. And I still don't understand how that is done, if there indeed is such an alternative.

Comment: The automatic creation only happens if something gets added through the `add()` method but this is not persistent, eg. it would only exist if the adding happens in the same request...

Comment: So again I get the perception that there is some other way to do this where I use the `add` method. I still wonder how. If the answer is that I can't do that when I'm using `through` but I need to explicitly say which models I'm using I can understand that, but what I'm hearing is instead that there is a way to do this.

I should also say that this question was prompted by an answer to [this question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353833/django-m2m-through-extra-fields-with-multiple-models) where gave an example similar to mine without explicitly specifying models.)